# Dispatcher.RunOnUIThread takes time to run the code

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, uwp-xaml

I have a background task (Task.Run) after the execution of that, I need to update the UI, so I put a the UI updation code in "Dispatcher.RunOnUIThread) but that code get executed after a minimal delay of say 60ms any reasons for this. This happens event thought I run the dispathcher code with priority high(CoreDispatcherPriority.High).

Comment: why don't you just use the dispatcher normally then ?

Comment: Even in normal mode it takes around 60ms

Comment: have you tried Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
            {/*youractionhere*/});

Comment: Window.Current gives me null when accessed from another thread.

Comment: It's not up to you to decide when to execute your code on the UI thread.

Comment: ill prepare a full fledged answer for that issue later on.

Comment: @Bite so when the app needs to be back to UI thread without delay what can be done.

Comment: Can you share your code? And if 60ms is too long to wait, what is an acceptable amount of time to wait?